# Identify build for angular application

Tags: angular

I have a angular application which has multiple projects. So with in this application let's say I have project A, Project B, Project C.

I can build any of the project and distribute.

There is one common project lets say Project common.
I want to create the menu for the application based on the project is being build.

For example if I use the command ng build --prod --project=A
I need to have X menu list for this project. Similarly Y list of menus for Project B etc.

Can please some one suggest on this.
Thanks

Comment: Why it is voted down, I have a problem and require guidance on that.

Comment: Yes you make Mano repo type projects and share your between them

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to use a local package as a project dependency. If that's the case you can use  'yalc' to manage local packages. You can publish a package to your local yalc store and install it in required projects.

You can follow this [guide](https://www.viget.com/articles/how-to-use-local-unpublished-node-packages-as-project-dependencies/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have some success with getting help from community when ask more specific question. As I see you should create some wrap above `ng build` command (e.g. js script) and it should change some settings of your angular projects A, B, C and may be common project. Try to research environments configs

```
└──myProject/src/environments/
                   └──environment.ts
                   └──environment.prod.ts
```

You may change content of these json files by your new code to any values you need. Also you may find more information in [evironment docs](https://angular.io/guide/build).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this while having a config.js file for each of the project and loading them through index.html file. This way I can figure which all  build are being built.